# ArrayIndexOutOfBounds When Splitting String

Tags: java, arrays, bufferedreader, indexoutofboundsexception

I am trying to extract information from a file that is formatted as follows:

```
1
test@mail.ca|password|false
```

However, I seem to be getting `ArrayIndexOutOfBounds` errors when running the following code and I am unable to determine the reason for this as I believe that my splitting should be functioning correctly. The error is obtained on the line beginning with "users".

```
        sc = new Scanner (System.in);
        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader (new FileReader (USAVE));
        int repeats = Integer.parseInt(in.readLine());
        for (int c = 0; c < repeats; c++){
            String info = in.readLine();
            System.out.println (info);
            String[] extracted = info.split("\\|");
            users.addUser(extracted[0], decryptPassword(extracted[1]));
        }
        in.close();
```

What could be the problem?

EDIT: I have changed "|" to "\|" but the problem persists.

EDIT2: StackTrace

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 1
at OnlineCommunications.userFromFile(OnlineCommunications.java:165)
at OnlineCommunications.logIn(OnlineCommunications.java:36)
at OnlineCommunications.emailOption(OnlineCommunications.java:593)
at OnlineCommunications.main(OnlineCommunications.java:683)
```

The method I have posted above is the one named `userFromFile`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[**String#split(regex)**](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split%28java.lang.String%29) expects regex as a parameter and `|` is a meta character(special character) in regex world. In order to treat a meta charcter as a normal character you should escape it with backslash(\|)

```
String[] extracted = info.split("\\|");
```

or just include it inside a charcter class

```
String[] extracted = info.split("[|]");
```

Below are the meta characters in regex:

```
<([{\^-=$!|]})?*+.>
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer but it seems that I'm still getting the error. :( I had previously tried using "," to separate the values as well.

Comment: @mCode if i apply the split to `test@mail.ca|password|false` i get emailadd at index 0 password at index 1 and false at index 2. are you sure this is thesource of your exception. can you update the post with stacktrace please.

Comment: @PremGenError I have updated with a stacktrace (I am not sure what a stacktrace is so please let me know if that is not it).

Comment: @mCode whats on line 165 ?? and are you sure info prints out `test@mail.ca|password|false`??

Comment: @PremGenError Line 165 contains `users.addUser(extracted[0], decryptPassword(extracted[1]));`. I am assuming that `info` should be putting out the mentioned String because the `in.readLine()` should be telling it to behave as such. Perhaps it is an error of the BufferedReader? I should add that `System.out.println(info);` does not print anything before the error.

Answer (score 2):

[`String.split(String regex)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split%28java.lang.String%29) takes a regular expression as an argument, use:

```
String[] extracted = info.split("\\|");
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer but it seems that I'm still getting the error. :( I had previously tried using "," to separate the values as well.

Answer (score 1):

similar post. [Tokenizing Error: java.util.regex.PatternSyntaxException, dangling metacharacter '*'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/917822/tokenizing-error-java-util-regex-patternsyntaxexception-dangling-metacharacter) You have to use like this :

```
String[] extracted = info.split("\\|");
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer but it seems that I'm still getting the error. :( I had previously tried using "," to separate the values as well.

Answer (score 0):

Actually there is nothing wrong with how you are parsing the string. The error lies elsewhere.  I would add System.out.println (repeats) just before you enter the loop to make sure you are iterating the correct number of times.  To debug even further, I would print the contents of extracted (Arrays.toString(extracted)) before the line invoking user.addUsers. If all that looks good, then the problem lies in the user.addUsers invocation.

Comment: I would look closer at what is going on in the user.addUser line. You didn't post the code, so I can't help you there. But, if you take that line out and just println extracted[0] and extracted[1] you don't get ANY errors.