# .replaceAll() method not working correctly

Tags: java, regex, string

As a bit of background to the problem I load in a text file and then assign a phrase from that text file to become a randomPirateWord, I then change the letters into that text file to become **'s and that works correctly. However when I am asking the user to guess a letter, it doesn't work correctly, if they guess incorrectly then the code works fine but if they guess a letter correctly the code doesn't work properly. I have put the error message below the code:

```
if (!escape.equalsIgnoreCase("m")){
                    System.out.print(" Type the letter you want to guess: ");
                    char letter = input.nextLine().charAt(0); 

if(m.getRandomPirateWord().contains(letter+"")){
                        System.out.println(m.getRandomPirateWord().replaceAll("*",letter+""));
                    }
```

---

```
Error message:
Exception in thread "main" java.util.regex.PatternSyntaxException: Dangling meta character '*' near index 0
*
^
    at java.util.regex.Pattern.error(Pattern.java:1924)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern.sequence(Pattern.java:2090)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern.expr(Pattern.java:1964)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern.compile(Pattern.java:1665)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern.<init>(Pattern.java:1337)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern.compile(Pattern.java:1022)
    at java.lang.String.replaceAll(String.java:2162)
    at uk.ac.aber.dcs.pirate_hangman.TextBasedGame.runTextBasedGame(TextBasedGame.java:45)
    at uk.ac.aber.dcs.pirate_hangman.Application.runApplication(Application.java:19)
    at uk.ac.aber.dcs.pirate_hangman.Main.main(Main.java:6)
```

Comment: how is this related to Swing?

Comment: I guess simply googling the error or reading the things that popped up when you typed in the subject was out of the question? Duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/917822/tokenizing-error-java-util-regex-patternsyntaxexception-dangling-metacharacter

Comment: BTW, how are you going to decide which `*` to replace? Both `replace()` and `replaceAll()` will replace all the `*`s.

Comment: I'm really unsure how to determine which * to replace, do you have any recommendations?

Answer (score 5):

Use `String#replace()` instead of `String#replaceAll()`. The later one uses regex pattern for replacement, where `*` is a meta-character, and needs to be escaped.

Answer (score 1):

Use the following, You have to escape the `*` character, since replaceAll() method accepts [regular expression](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#sum) as one argument

```
replaceAll("\\*",letter+"")
```

Comment: When I do that it displays the whole word for example
The phrase is: ****** * ***** ***
I typed in: a
And it printed out: you're a bilge rat

Comment: @user228908 : I don't get you.

Comment: I originally have a word say for example hello, I then replace it into stars so it would become *****  I then ask the user for input of a guess of the letter so for example if they typed h I would want it do display h**** but for some reason if they guess a letter correctly it's displaying the whole word. Hope that makes more sense.

Comment: @user228908 Read my comment on your question. I guess you're approaching this problem wrongly. You need to get the actual position of the letter guessed from the original string, and replace the `*` at that position only. Simple `replace()` will not work.

Answer (score 0):

Check out below Example.

```
import java.io.*;

public class Test{
   public static void main(String args[]){
      String Str = new String("Welcome to Tutorialspoint.com");

      System.out.print("Return Value :" );
      System.out.println(Str.replaceAll("(.*)Tutorials(.*)",
                         "AMROOD" ));
   }
}
```

Syntax of method :

```
public String replaceAll(String regex, String replacement)
```

- regex -- the regular expression to which this string is to be matched.
- replacement -- the string which would replace found expression.

OUTPUT: **AMROOD**

Reference : [Regex replacement](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_string_replaceall.htm)

Answer (score -1):

The problem is that * is a reserved character in regexes, so you need to escape it.

```
replaceAll("\\*",letter+"")
```

Comment: Wasn't me, someone seems to be down voting everyone on this page.

Answer (score -1):

‘*’ symbol is used to identify a group from the regular expression which is the first parameter of ‘replaceAll’ or ‘replaceFirst’ method

```
1. Using ‘replace’ method: This would be the good choice if you want to replace a string literal and not a pattern.


2. Escaping ‘*’ symbol: If you need to a use regular expression, and your pattern has no groups identified, then you can escape any group identification symbols from your replace string as shown below:



String replaceValue = java.util.regex.Matcher.quoteReplacement("*100");
```