# Dangling metacharacter Java

Tags: java, string, metacharacters

I'm trying to search for a substring in a string and replace it. I'm using

```
String p= "+ 0.0";
```

But this line gives me a dangling metacharacter error. I've tried typecasting this but it still doesn't work. How do I fix this?

I want to do the following

```
if(s.containts(p)){ //s is a given string
s.replaceAll(p,"");
}
```

On a related note,

`s.containts("+ 0.0"))` throws no dangling metacharater error but
`s.replaceAll("+ 0.0","");` throws the error.

Is there a reason for this?

Comment: So what exactly are you doing with that `p` variable, is that what you eventually use as a regular expression during replacement? Then this is basically the same issue as here, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/917822/

Comment: Apparently you’re performing a regex match operation. So you need to learn about [the syntax](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html), to quote meta characters or just use [`Pattern.quote`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#quote-java.lang.String-)… In case you’re using `String.replaceAll(String,String)`, just consider using [`String.replace(CharSequence,CharSequence)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replace-java.lang.CharSequence-java.lang.CharSequence-) instead.

Comment: The obvious method to use is [`replace`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replace-java.lang.CharSequence-java.lang.CharSequence-), which does not produce "dangling metacharacter" errors. Apparently you're using something different, though you have not posted a [mcve].

Comment: take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4316710/string-replaceall-without-regex

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Escape the `+` and `.`, since `+` and `.` are meta characters of a regular expression.

```
String p= "\\+ 0\\.0";
```

Comment: If they are using a regular expression, they should escape the `.` as well, though there is no clear need for a regular expression at all.

Comment: @khelwood Fixed. I agree but it depends upon what OP is doing.

Comment: The \\ worked, it was required for the '.' though