# How do I escape a special Regex character?

Tags: java, regex

I've encountered a problem in Java, specific to the String.split function.
I'm porting my C# code to Java, and something bothers Java. My C# code is as follows :

```
foreach (char sep in separators)
    if (text.Contains(sep.ToString()))
        array = text.Reverse().Split(sep);
```

`Reverse()` is an extension I've made myself which just reverses a string.
`separators` is a char array that contains a few separators :

```
char[] separators = { '&', '!', '#', '?', '%' };
```

Now, in Java, my code is as follows :

```
for (char sep : separators) {
    String sepp = String.valueOf(sep);
    if (text.contains(sepp))
        array = new StringBuilder(text).reverse().toString().split(sepp);
}
```

The problem with this code is that, when I have the specific separator `?` (it's randomly choosed), then it throws me this error (Java only) :

```
Exception in thread "main" java.util.regex.PatternSyntaxException: Dangling meta character '?' near index 0
at java.base/java.util.regex.Pattern.error(Pattern.java:2027)
at java.base/java.util.regex.Pattern.sequence(Pattern.java:2202)
at java.base/java.util.regex.Pattern.expr(Pattern.java:2068)
at java.base/java.util.regex.Pattern.compile(Pattern.java:1782)
at java.base/java.util.regex.Pattern.<init>(Pattern.java:1428)
at java.base/java.util.regex.Pattern.compile(Pattern.java:1068)
at java.base/java.lang.String.split(String.java:2317)
at java.base/java.lang.String.split(String.java:2364)
at com.anerruption.encryption.Main.decrypt(Main.java:58)
at com.anerruption.encryption.Main.main(Main.java:43)
```

My guess is that the function `string.Split` in C# doesn't use Regex, but the one in Java does. From what I've heard, I need to escape the character. Doing `\\?` did not work. How could I do this?

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: private String[] separators = new String[] {"\?"}; or \\?

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/917822/tokenizing-error-java-util-regex-patternsyntaxexception-dangling-metacharacter

Comment: @Curiosity "Invalid escape sequence (valid ones are  \b  \t  \n  \f  \r  \"  \'  \\ )".

Comment: I suggested string not char[]

Comment: @Curiosity still, with your line it says that error msg.

Comment: What string are you passing?

Comment: I passed "abc?def" and the error is gone. check it again. String[] separators = { "&", "!", "#", "\\?", "%" };

Comment: Check my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use this way, by concatenating `"\\"` to each separator only for `split()` method

```
char[] separators = { '&', '!', '#', '?', '%' };

for (char sep : separators) {
    if (text.contains(sep+""))
       array = new StringBuilder(text).reverse().toString().split("\\"+sep);
}
```

Comment: Like I said in my question, adding "\\" in a character doesn't work.

Comment: I saw it, but may be you did it in a wrong way, this 2 solutions worked for me, did you try to copy/paste them? if yes what is the error shown.

Comment: I tried with your way, it just shows blank text (I'm doing a simple cipher, but the decrypted text is nothing when I add "\\" in the characters (if I don't it's fine except for the "?" character)

Comment: yea yea, I am sorry, now it is fixed, actually you should use "\\" ONLY for split method. now it should works, sorry again

Comment: For some reason, I've tried this before and it didn't work. Now it works, note that I've made my char array a String array because it was easier to work with.

Comment: @ShiningLea this because I edited the answer, may be you didn't pay attention. anyway glade to hear that it was solved

Answer (score 1):

Meta Character Description .........................................Escape character

```
*   zero or more occurrence of the characters        \\*
+   one or more occurrence of the characters         \\+ 
?   zero or only one occurrence of the characters    \\? 
^   Start of the character sequence                  \\^
$   End of the character sequence                    \\$
```

Example of ?

```
 public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    String[] separators = { "&", "!", "#", "\\?", "%" };
    String str = "Parth?Prem";
    String str2 = "\\?";
    String[] strArray;

    strArray = str.split(str2);

    System.out.println("Given String : " + str);
    for(int i=0;i<strArray.length;i++) {
        System.out.println("strArray["+i+"] = " + strArray[i]);
    }
    
}
```

**Output:**

> Given String : Parth?Prem
>
> strArray[0] = Parth
>
> strArray[1] = Prem