# How to replace ? from string with another string in java

Tags: java, string, replace, replaceall

How to replace a ? from string with another.
Here is my sample code

```
String oldString = "I am ? ?";
String newString = oldString.replaceAll("?|?", "Java|Developer");
System.out.println(newString);
```

and gives error

```
Exception in thread "main" java.util.regex.PatternSyntaxException: Dangling meta character '?' near index 0
```

If I use another way like

```
String oldString = "I am J D";
String newString = oldString.replaceAll("J|D", "Java|Developer");
System.out.println(newString);
```

and the output is

```
I am Java|Developer Java|Developer
```

My requirement is

```
Input: I am ? ?
Output: I am Java Developer
```

Is there any way to achieve it?

Comment: Read a regular expression tutrial, e.g. https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/

Comment: Well, one not-too-elegant way would be `oldString.replace("?", "%s").formatted("Java", "Developer")`.

Comment: @MCEmperor the way is working for characters not the "?". Is there any way to use "?".

Comment: I have found the solution for `"?"` to `"\\?"` from https://stackoverflow.com/a/23864310/16974685

Comment: @AlyanAhmed Read carefully. I used `replace` instead of `replaceAll`.

Comment: @MCEmperor no changes on `replace` for `"\\?"` but `replaceAll` is working for `"\\?"`